# Restore of an in-app non-consumable product in Codenameone

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, codenameone

My issue, i really need help with, is that i can't get the logic working which renders the 'Restore Purchase' button conditionally.

I have built my IOS app with an in-app purchase button that allows the user to pay once to unlock extra features - of type "Non-Consumable Product". The purchase feature works fine in TestFlight using my regular home user Apple IDs and some other Test Apple IDs (not sandbox testers). I don't have a Mac and so can't use a Sandbox environment. When the trial period is up i display the Purchase button, this invokes the CN1 Purchase API and PurchaseCallback, and i then use Storage to store the flag that its been purchased.

```
        purchaseApp.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (Purchase.getInAppPurchase().wasPurchased("full_product")) {
            ToastBar.showMessage("You have already previously purchased this product.", FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO);
        ...
        } else {
            Purchase p = Purchase.getInAppPurchase();
            p.purchase("full_product");
        }
    });
```

(I am not doing anything with receipts or receipt_stores.)

But to comply with Apple i need a 'Restore Purchase' button, so users don't pay again on new devices. The difficulty is getting the logic right, as i only want the Restore button to display IF they have paid for it before, else i just want the Purchase button displayed.

So i created the userHasPreviousPurchased() method below to test for the button to show, and added RestoreCallback interface to my main class as per CN1 documentation. But the method below never returns true on my IPhone using a TestFlight build, so my Restore button never shows. It is that p.getReceipts() always returns an empty List, when i expect 1 row with my SKU in it.

```
    private boolean userHasPreviousPurchased() {

    Purchase p = Purchase.getInAppPurchase();
    if (p.isRestoreSupported()) {
        p.synchronizeReceipts();
        List<Receipt> receipts = p.getReceipts();
        for (Receipt receipt : receipts) {
            if (receipt.getSku().equalsIgnoreCase("full_product")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please can you point me in the right direction. Using CN1 API's how do you test for a previous purchase using this type of IAP?

I tried creating a sandbox test user and, after signing out on my device, purchasing the IAP using the user (which was accepted). I have debug code in my app with tests the above method and that still didn't return a receipt (i fail to see how it could have as i wasn't signed in as the sandbox user).

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep track of who has purchased your products already, you need to have a server-side component to store this.  The Receipts API depends on this, and requires you to implement a ReceiptStore.  Check out these blog posts that cover this in detail.

- [Introduction to In-App Purchase](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/intro-to-in-app-purchase.html)
- [Non-renewable Subscriptions](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/in-app-purchase-non-renewable-subscriptions.html) - This introduces you to ReceiptStores and how they work.
- [Auto-renewing Subscriptions in iOS and Android](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/autorenewing-subscriptions-in-ios-and-android.html) - This includes full sample code for client and server for Android and iOS.

Comment: Very comprehensive blogs you've put together. I am using a non-consumable product, rather than subscription, but the Appstore are requiring me still have a Restore facility, hence the original query. Is it likely they misunderstand my app, or is that you just Have to track receipts (and so have the server) when doing IAPs on the Appstore? If it is, then I had naively thought that the Appstore was the 'server' holding onto the receipts, that i was then refreshing from. From the blogs i would have to create my own server to hold receipts. I think this is a blocker to me using IAP sadly. Thanks

Comment: Further to the above, reading Apples developer guidelines, they state that "Users restore transactions to maintain access to content they’ve already purchased...In most cases, all your app needs to do is refresh its receipt and deliver the products in its receipt...Refreshing the receipt asks the App Store for the latest copy of the receipt." It's reading this that makes me question the need for me to hold receipts on my own database when the AppStore should be able to do this for me ?  Many thanks again

Comment: In your case, you can just detect whether the purchase has been loaded on the device by checking your storage variable.  If it is not present, then given them the restore functionality.  You don't need to track the receipt for that case. Being any more slick is difficult.

Comment: Please can i double-check before i invest the time @steve-hannah. Apple rejected me as the 2nd device under the same AppleID needs the Restore - but i don't have any data source available to me, from that second device, to check. Hence am i right that the only solution is as per your blog on Subscriptions, ie. creating my own server and db and JSON storing/reading the purchase on there? There's no other mechanism in CN1 API's to read Apple direct? If that's the case, is there a way to get the users AppleID to store, otherwise i have to deal with Usernames and Passwords\ Password resets. Thx.

Comment: Correcting my tag @steve

Comment: Most apps just add an option to restore purchases that is always available.  The user pressed the button, and if there are purchases to restore, then they are restored, if not, then nothing really happens.  If you want to download the receipt I think you can do it using native APIs (you would need to write a native interface).  [This article](https://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/receipt-validation/) describes what you can do with the app's receipt.